# gitkraken failed to connect to gitlab invalid argument

Tags: gitlab, gitkraken

I want to connect to my school gitlab (self-hosted) with gitkraken.
It create the repo when i try to init but a few second later i get this error :

> failed to connect to (school.gitlab.url) invalid argument

I'm on win7 x64

gitkraken v4.0.5

- I'm connected to the gitlab on gitkraken and my SSH key is good.
- I also try to desactivate my firewall but no change.

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would set up a proxy, that fixed it for me. 
*On windows:*
Press win key
Type proxy settings
Turn on use a proxy server
Type in IP and port (google free proxies to find one)
Press save
GitKraken should detect the proxy